# Uniforms not working after changing them to uniform blocks

Tags: opengl, glsl, uniform

I have just switched my matrix uniforms to a single block but they are no longer working even though I have not changed the way my matrices are generated, only the way they get into the shader

My uniform block is defined as such:

```
layout(row_major, std140) uniform MatrixBlock {
    mat4 model;
    mat4 view;
    mat4 proj;
};
```

I set up the uniform block as such:

```
void UniformBlock::generateBuffer() {
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, size(), NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
    glBindBufferRange(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, bindingIndex, buffer, 0, size());
    glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

`size()` just returns `192` in this case.

I then bind the the program to the binding index like so:

```
void UniformBlock::bind(GLuint program) const {
    GLuint index = glGetUniformBlockIndex(program, getBlockName().c_str());

    if(index != GL_INVALID_INDEX) {
        glUniformBlockBinding(program, index, getBindingIndex());
    }
}
```

`getBlockName()` returns `"MatrixBlock"` in this case.

then I set the matrices using:

```
void MatrixBlock::bindMatrix(size_t offset, const Matrix4& matrix) {
    MatrixBlock& self = instance();

    glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, self.getBuffer());
    glBufferSubData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER,
                    offset * Matrix4::size(),
                    Matrix4::size(),
                    matrix.asArray()); //Matrix4 holds the actual matrix data in a std::array<float, 16>, this method gets the std::array.begin()
    glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

where `offset` is one of these:

```
enum Variables {
    MODEL = 0,
    VIEW = 1,
    PROJECTION = 2,
};
```

`MatrixBlock` is just a subclass to `UniformBlock` (it's a singleton hence the first line)

`Matrix4::size()` returns `sizeof(float) * 16`

Now when I query the size of the uniform's variables like so:

```
GLuint blockIndex;
GLuint indices[3];
GLint offsets[3];
GLsizei sizes[3];

glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, MatrixBlock::instance().getBuffer());
blockIndex = glGetUniformBlockIndex(getProgram(), "MatrixBlock");
glGetActiveUniformBlockiv(getProgram(), blockIndex, GL_UNIFORM_BLOCK_ACTIVE_UNIFORM_INDICES, (GLint*)indices);
glGetActiveUniformsiv(getProgram(), 3, indices, GL_UNIFORM_OFFSET, offsets);
glGetActiveUniformsiv(getProgram(), 3, indices, GL_UNIFORM_SIZE, sizes);
glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0);
```

I get this

```
Name               Index Offset Size
MatrixBlock.model  0     0      1
MatrixBlock.view   1     64     1
MatrixBlock.proj   2     128    1
```

Why is the size reporting as one? Should it not be 64? Is this the source of my problem?

---

You can view the entire source on github here: [lerp@github](http://www.github.com/lerp/vox)

Comment: Are your matrices actually in row-major ordering? "*Why is the size reporting as one?*" Because the size the size of the *array*. Since each value is a single value (of `mat4` type), the size is 1.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes, before I was changed it I was passing `GL_TRUE` as the value for transpose.